# Python type checking in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've recently learned about typing module in Python (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and expected to use it for static type checking and for better intellisense in VS Code, like it works with TypeScript, but I can't seem to find any tools/plugins that actually do that.

What are my options, if any?

Comment: SO isn't an advice forum; Answers to this type of question would be primarily opinion-based and many of them would go out of date pretty quickly.

Comment: Have you looked into [pythonVSCode](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode) and its mypy integration?

Comment: I have pythonVSCode extension installed, but it does not seem to care about type annotations in any way.

Comment: I got VS Code to indicate type issues using 'type hints' by installing [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and [Pyright](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-pyright.pyright) extensions. Now it shows a squiggly red line under the erroneous piece of code similarly to typescript.

Answer (score 34):

### from bash

```sh
mkdir test
cd test
python3 -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate
python -m pip install flake8
python -m pip install flake8-mypy
code ./
```

### install plugin

then install this in VSCode
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python
and config

### settings

> ./.vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
    "python.pythonPath": ".env/bin/python",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
}
```

> ./.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### OMG, this is Python 3 only!

> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8-mypy/17.3.3
>
> Yes, so is mypy. Relax, you can run Flake8 with all popular plugins
>   as a tool perfectly fine under Python 3.5+ even if you want to analyze
>   Python 2 code. This way you’ll be able to parse all of the new syntax
>   supported on Python 3 but also effectively all the Python 2 syntax at
>   the same time.
>
> By making the code exclusively Python 3.5+, I’m able to focus on the
>   quality of the checks and re-use all the nice features of the new
>   releases (check out pathlib) instead of wasting cycles on Unicode
>   compatibility, etc.

### IDE & Linter Integrations

> https://github.com/python/mypy#ide--linter-integrations
>
> IDE & Linter Integrations
>
> Mypy can be integrated into popular IDEs:
>
> - Vim: vim-mypy
> - Emacs: using Flycheck and Flycheck-mypy
> - Sublime Text: SublimeLinter-contrib-mypy
> - Atom: linter-mypy
> - PyCharm: PyCharm integrates its own implementation of PEP 484.
>
> Mypy can also be integrated into Flake8 using flake8-mypy.

### o ,-

- https://github.com/python/mypy
- https://pypi.org/project/flake8-mypy
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: if someone have troubles with `flake8-mypy`, you're can use both `flake8` and `mypy` linters in vscode-python!!!

Answer (score 4):

I added the following code

```
{
    "name": "mypy",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "mypy",
    "args": [
        "${file}"
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

in VS Code launch.json and now it is visible in "DEBUG" window. Just press F5 and you you get full static analysis of the current file.